# Angular forkJoin Subscribe not firing

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a couple of methods in the form of

```typescript
    getFirstDataBunch() {
        return this.repository.getData(this.parameter).pipe(
            switchMap(
                result => {
                    //Do something with result;
                    return of(true);
                }
            )
        );
    }
```

Which I then call on my `ngOnInit` as:

```typescript
    function ngOnInit(){
        forkJoin(this.getFirstDataBunch(), this.getSecondDataBunch(), this.getThirdDataBunch()).subscribe(
            results => {
                //do stuff with results; 
            }
        );
    }
```

I can see that all the observables are being called, and they return an observable, however the `forkJoin` Subscribe method is never called, from what I've read `forkJoin` fires only when all observables return and are finished, and I do believe that to be the case, so why is not firing?

I've also seen that some people simply go for `combineLatest`, but because these methods only return once I don't really need to keep looking for updates on them.

Comment: Apparently, at least one of the `dataBunch()` streams doesn't complete. Did you check that?

Comment: @mbojko how would I do that? Functions are exactly as you see here, I do a GET request for some data, do some transformations, then return an observable of(true) just so the switchMap does have a return type Observable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply use the combination operator that you want/need and pipe it with a `take(1)`.

Why the `take()` operator?

Because *take* returns an Observable that emits only the first **X** values emitted by the source Observable. We set how many emissions.

Example:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit 1,2,3,4,5
const source = of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
//take the first emitted value then complete
const example = source.pipe(take(1));
//output: 1
const subscribe = example.subscribe(console.log);

//output: 1, 2, 3
const example2 = source.pipe(take(3)).subscribe(console.log);
```

If you want to be 100% sure to avoid any possible memory leak, I suggest using also `takeUntil()` (since take(1) can be stuck forever for some reason, if the observable never emits)

```
.pipe(take(1), takeUntil(this.destroy$))
```

As a general suggestion, place always `takeUntil()` as the last argument of your pipe.

About what combination operator:

`forkJoin` --> as you wrote, waits for all observables to complete and then emits the last emitted value from each (like a `Promise.all`). It would work, but each observable needs to complete (not just emit!).

`zip` --> waits for all observables to emit, then emit values as an array (in sequence order - picture below). I would probably use this.

`combineLatest` --> Waits for all observables to emit, emits once. Then whenever any input Observable emits a value, it emits the new value of the observable that emitted and the last emission of the others (who didn't emit). Sure, that would work too with `take(1)`...

[image: zip example]

Answer (score 2):

your methods are not completed, you should complete it manually via `first()` operator or `take(1)`.

```
function ngOnInit(){
        forkJoin(
         this.getFirstDataBunch().pipe(first()), 
         this.getSecondDataBunch().pipe(first()), 
         this.getThirdDataBunch().pipe(first())
        ).subscribe(
            results => {
                //do stuff with results; 
            }
        );
    }
```