# Combine multiple Observable subscription results in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable, subscribe

(1) I have a request in Firebase firestore where I get several 'nomBu' strings from a collection. **OK**

(2) Then, with these recovered 'nomBu' strings, I make a second request to get metedata from another collection where the 'nomBu' is present. **OK**

(3) I would like to display data in a dashboard in HTML. **OK** **But I can only get 1 observable result in my dashboard (the last one executed)**

My code (1 and 2 and 3)

```
demandesSaaSEvaluator: Demande[];

fire.collection('businessUnit')
.where('evaluators', 'array-contains', this.auth.currentUserEmail).get() //(1)
          .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
//for each matching 'nomBu' get his metadata
this.service.getEvaluatorSaaSRequests(doc.data().nomBu).subscribe(actionArray => { //(2)
              this.demandesSaaSEvaluator = actionArray.map(item => {
            
                return { //display in HTML (3)
                  id: item.payload.doc.id,
                  ...(item.payload.doc.data() as object)
                } as Demande;
              
              });
            });
            });
           });
```

My code (2)

```
getEvaluatorSaaSRequests(nomBu) { //should be executed several time
    return this.firestore
      .collection('solutions', ref => 
        ref.where('businessUnitOfSolution', '==', nomBu).where('type', '==', 'SaaS')
      )
      .snapshotChanges();
  }
```

My code (3)

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let demande of demandesSaaSEvaluator; let i = index">
      <td>{{ demande.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ demande.solutionName }}</td>
      <td>{{ demande.nomBu }}</td>
      <td>{{ demande.user }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

With code above I can only display/get one observable result (the last one executed) => I would like to combine all observable subscription results to display the dashboard with all executed request results.

**Workaround**:

```
demandesSaaSEvaluator: Demande[]: [];

this.service.getEvaluatorSaaSRequests(doc.data().nomBu).subscribe(actionArray => {               
  this.demandesSaaSEvaluator.push(...actionArray.map(item => {
    return {
      id: item.payload.doc.id,
      ...(item.payload.doc.data() as object)
    } as Demande;      
  }));
});
```

However with my workaround I get good results from my Observable (multiple observable subsciptions in my dashboard) but twice. How can I avoid that ?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

Comment: @DeWetvanAs do you have a snippet example for my case ?

Comment: finally found solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800019/angular-forkjoin-subscribe-not-firing with take(1)

Answer (score 0):

Try shareReplay to avoid double

```
getEvaluatorSaaSRequests(nomBu) { //should be executed several time
  return this.firestore.collection(
    'solutions', ref => ref.where(
      'businessUnitOfSolution', '==', nomBu
    ).where('type', '==', 'SaaS')).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      shareReplay(1)
    );
}
```

Comment: shareReplay(1) does not changes anything unfortunatly...

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue just with `take(1)`:

```
getEvaluatorSaaSRequests(nomBu) { //should be executed several time
  return this.firestore.collection(
    'solutions', ref => ref.where(
      'businessUnitOfSolution', '==', nomBu
    ).where('type', '==', 'SaaS')).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      take(1)
    );
}
```