# Combine multiple Observable subscription results in Angular with forkJoin

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable, subscribe

(1) I have a request in Firebase firestore where I get several 'nomBu' strings from a collection. **OK**

(2) Then, with these recovered 'nomBu' strings, I make a second request to get metedata from another collection where the 'nomBu' is present. **OK**

(3) I would like to display data in a dashboard in HTML. **OK** **But I can only get 1 observable result in my dashboard (the last one executed)**

My code (1 and 2 and 3)

```
demandesSaaSEvaluator: Demande[];

fire.collection('businessUnit')
.where('evaluators', 'array-contains', this.auth.currentUserEmail).get() //(1)
          .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
//for each matching 'nomBu' get his metadata
this.service.getEvaluatorSaaSRequests(doc.data().nomBu).subscribe(actionArray => { //(2)
              this.demandesSaaSEvaluator = actionArray.map(item => {
            
                return { //display in HTML (3)
                  id: item.payload.doc.id,
                  ...(item.payload.doc.data() as object)
                } as Demande;
              
              });
            });
            });
           });
```

My code (2)

```
getEvaluatorSaaSRequests(nomBu) { //should be executed several time
    return this.firestore
      .collection('solutions', ref => 
        ref.where('businessUnitOfSolution', '==', nomBu).where('type', '==', 'SaaS')
      )
      .snapshotChanges();
  }
```

My code (3)

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let demande of demandesSaaSEvaluator; let i = index">
      <td>{{ demande.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ demande.solutionName }}</td>
      <td>{{ demande.nomBu }}</td>
      <td>{{ demande.user }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

With code above I can only display/get one observable result (the last one executed) => I would like to combine all observable subscription results to display the dashboard with all executed request results.

**Workaround**:

```
demandesSaaSEvaluator: Demande[]: [];

this.service.getEvaluatorSaaSRequests(doc.data().nomBu).subscribe(actionArray => {               
  this.demandesSaaSEvaluator.push(...actionArray.map(item => {
    return {
      id: item.payload.doc.id,
      ...(item.payload.doc.data() as object)
    } as Demande;      
  }));
});
```

However with my workaround I get good results from my Observable (multiple observable subsciptions in my dashboard) but not combined, I get twice. How can I avoid that ? **It seems forkJoin should be the good idea** https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin but I don't know how to match with my code.

Zip or take from rxjs could also match with my case ? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800019/angular-forkjoin-subscribe-not-firing)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it like below.

1. For each result of collection in the loop, add them in observable array
2. Use this observable array for forkJoin
3. Do necessary mapping from the fokJoin result

   ```js
   let filterEvaluator$ = fire
     .collection('businessUnit')
     .where('evaluators', 'array-contains', this.auth.currentUserEmail)
     .get();

   let getEvaluatorRequestsObservables: [] = [];

   filterEvaluator$.pipe(
     //concatMap will wait for filterEvaluator$ to finish
     concatMap((result: any) => { 
       result.forEach((doc) => {
         //push them all to observable array which we will use in forkJoin
         this.getEvaluatorObservables.push(
           this.service.getEvaluatorSaaSRequests(doc.data().nomBu)
         );
       });
       //add checking if getEvaluatorRequestsObservables is empty as needed
       return forkJoin(getEvaluatorRequestsObservables);
     })
    ).subscribe(([forkJoinResultInArray]) => {
     //do corresponding handling to update demandesSaaSEvaluator
    });
   ```